# Unwrapping 3 c++ loops in cuda

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

I am currently writing a program that picks out 2D blocks of a big 2D array and puts them into a smaller 2D array. The arrays are actualy saved as 1D arrays but i assume they are 2D arrays that are straightened out. Right now for loops make sure i take out Nx, Ny elemtents of the big loop before moving on to a new part of the big array.

I cant really figure out a way to do this datatransfering more efficiently in a CUDA kernel. I would have been able to make a solution if i had just to arrays of equal size. But with a new location after each Nx*Ny element i am confused.

Below are the 3 for loops that make it all happen. posx and posy contain coordinates which need to have starting positions subtracted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < loadsize; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < Searchsizey; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < Searchsizex; l++)
            {
                img[count] = ImgInt[posx[i] - ImgStartx + (posy[i] - ImgStarty) * sizex + sizex*k + l];
                count++;
            }
        }
     }
```

The problem is that the two inner loops run to a maximum of Searchsizex and Searchsizey. If i am to implement this in a kernel using l and k as indexing from threads, these will become bigger than Searchsizex and Searchsizey.

I thought about making a CUDA kernel that iterates trough i but it doesent seem very efficient to do it this way. Below is what i thoguht about putting inside a kernel but i dont like it very much. Its only sort of "semi-parallel".

Hope you have some suggestions for how to make this parallel, thanks!

```
int l = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int k = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        for (int i = 0; i < loadsize; i++){
            img[l + k*sizex + (i*sizex*sizey)] = ImgInt[posx[i] - ImgStartx + (posy[i] - ImgStarty) * sizex + sizex*k + l];         
        }
```

Comment: Depending on sizes of your input and the magnitude of posx and posy, different approaches might fit. Could you provide approximate metrics for these? Also the data type of img ?

Comment: posx and posy could range from say 0 to 1000 and there the size of loadszie could be hundreds. Img is a float

Comment: To get best performance, you want to use float4 as writes and depending on target hardware, use texture or surface for ImgInt. For the rest, your approach of parallelism seems very sensible.

Comment: Hey Florent, thanks for your answer once again. Do you have some sources or anything for your suggestions? I would love to know why these data types improve speed as compared to current data types :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i guess as there have been no more responses to this thread i will use Florents comment as answer.

The writes need to be of type float4, and depending on target hardware, texture or surface datatype should be used for ImgInt.

Other than that the approach of parallelism seems very sensible.